# Assign value to pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, ascii

I need to place * on every lowercase letter, but my program blocks always. Although this seems like a simple problem I cant find simple solution. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void f(char *p)
{
    int i = 0;
    char c = '*';
    while(p[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(p[i]> 96 && p[i] < 122 )
        {
            p[i] = c; # here program block
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%c",p);
}

int main(void)
{
    f("tesT");
    return 1;
}
```

I found some similar problems on internet but without success. :(

Comment: This question is asked very frequently. [Please read any C FAQ.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot modify string literals.

Try:

```
int main(void)
{
   char buf[] = "tesT";

   f(buf);

   return 1;
}
```

also, never hardcode ASCII values, use `islower()` from `<ctype.h>`.